# Erro ao carregar o Antlr3.Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll

Hoje tive um problema de queda de energia e ao reiniciar o computador foi efetuado um scan completo. Aparentemente gerou alguns erros e acredito que um deles está relacionado com o problema que ocorreu a seguir.

Abri meu projeto no Visual Studio, C# e MVC e ao tentar rodar o seguinte problema ocorreu:

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' ou uma
>   de suas dependências. Parâmetro incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Já tentei excluir tudo da pasta TEMP, já tentei tirar todo vínculo da dll Antlr3.Runtime.dll do projeto e o problema persiste. Alguma solução?

Comment: Copiar o arquivo de novo?

Answer (score 1):

Possivelmente corrompeu o pacote. Abra o Package Manager Console e execute o seguinte comando:

```
PM> Update-Package Antlr -reinstall
```